# How to Open pdf hyperlink in internet explorer and go to specific page in Excel vba?

Tags: internet-explorer, vba, pdf

I wanna open the pdf hyperlink in internet explorer, then go to specific page using excel VBA.

Anybody knows how to do it? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `http://www.example.com/myfile.pdf#page=4`  http://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/link-html-pdf-page-acrobat.html

Answer (score 0):

The first comment above is useful for linking to specific pages. Below are two methods for using VBA to open those links.

You can use the FollowHyperlink method to simulate clicking a link. The link opens in the default browser, and the user will get a security prompt.

```
Sub OpenPDF_to_page_2_Method_1()
  Const PDF_PATH = "http://www.adobe.com/support/products/enterprise/knowledgecenter/media/c4611_sample_explain.pdf"
  ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink PDF_PATH & "#page=2"
End Sub
```

Alternately, you can create a new Internet Explorer object and navigate to the PDF. This uses Internet Explorer regardless of the default browser, and does not give the user a security prompt before opening the link.

```
Sub OpenPDF_to_page_2_Method_2()
  Const PDF_PATH = "http://www.adobe.com/support/products/enterprise/knowledgecenter/media/c4611_sample_explain.pdf"

  Dim IE As Object 
  Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
  IE.Visible = True
  IE.Navigate (PDF_PATH & "#page=2")
  Set IE = Nothing
End Sub
```